# <li> element not clickable

Tags: html, css, click, html-lists

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/wfhmtx8c/ so it works in jsfiddle?

```css
#nav {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 3em 0;
 padding: 0;
 opacity: 0.8;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
 float: left; }
#nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #069;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
 color: #c00;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: black; }
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Taal/Languague:</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Nederlands</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
 </ul>
```

But when I put it on my website: http://ub3rhd.nl it doesn't work?

The code is really the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is working perfectly fine for me. On hover, it changes color, and on click it redirects me to #.

Also, opacity on elements containing text is not exactly appealing. If i were you, i would get the opacity back at 100%. Language is spelled wrong, too. (: Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

They seem to work, but the style isn't as the one in the jsfiddle.

Edit: They look fine now.

Also, as another user said, the transparency on the menu-bar doesn't look good. :)